# If $V_1=\ker(P)$, $V_2=\ker(I-P)$ and $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$ then prove $P^2=P$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the reals and $P:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Let

$V_1=\ker(P)$

$V_2=\ker(I-P)$

and $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$

How would you prove $P^2=P$? I've been trying to show that $\mathrm{Im}(P)=\ker(I-p)$ as that would be equivalent.

Comment: $P$ is equal to $0$ on $V_1$ and to $1$ on $V_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $ \rm V_1 = \{ x\in V: P(x) = 0 \} $ and $\rm V_2 = \{ x\in V : P(x) = x \} .$

Let $\rm v_1 \in V_1 $ and $\rm v_2 \in V_2$. Then

$$\rm  (P^2-P)(v_1 + v_2) = P^2(v_1) + P^2(v_2) - P(v_1) - P(v_2) .$$

Since $\rm v_2 \in V_2$ we have $\rm  P^2 (v_2) = P( P(v_2) ) = P(v_2) $.  We know $\rm v_1 \in V_1$ so $\rm P(v_1) = 0 $ and $\rm  P^2(v_1) = P (P(v_1))=P(0) = 0$ as well. Thus $$\rm  (P^2-P)(v_1 + v_2) =0 $$ so $\rm P^2=P.$

Comment: Thanks! that's very helpful

Answer (score 5):

$(P-P^2)v_1 = (I-P)Pv_1 = 0$ for $v_1\in V_1$, and $(P-P^2)v_2 = P(I-P)v_2 = 0$ for $v_2\in V_2$.

Comment: That's clear, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $x\in V$, and decompose $x=x_1+x_2$.

You should then apply $P$ twice, and see that, indeed, $P(P(x))=P(x)$.

**Edit:** A more complete answer.

Let $x\in V$, and let $x_1\in V_1$ and $x_2\in V_2$ be the unique elements such that $x=x_1+x_2$.

By definition of $V_1$ and $V_2$, $P(x_1)=0$ and $x_2-P(x_2)=0$, so
\begin{align*}
P(x)&= P(x_1) + P(x_2)\\
&= 0 + x_2\\
P(P(x))&= P(0) + P(x_2)\\
&=x_2,
\end{align*}
so we have that
$$\forall x\in V, P^2(x)=P(x),$$
which proves indeed that $P^2=P$.

Comment: I take it you mean for $x_1$ to be in $V_1$, $x_2$ in $V_2$.

Comment: @Gerry: yes indeed, but seeing this is homework, the above was more intended as a hint than a definitive answer. :)

Comment: I take your point. I made a judgement that the hint was just a little too elliptical to be helpful. I might have been wrong.

Comment: @Gerry: Judging from the votes -- and the comments from the OP -- it seems you were right! I will try to be less elliptical in the future.